# How can i fetch checkbox inserted data from my database with a query

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, filter

Im busy on a checkbox search and upload for certain data. I am working with wordpress and for the storing of the data i am using a simple plugin that created a database and can insert data in the specific table/columns.

I have created a custom checkbox search function that allows user to fetch data with the use of checkbox submits. Although the function is working fine, it has a problem with data that is being uploaded by the use of checkboxes (so this is not the searching with checkboxes but the uploading). The thing is that my `foreach($_POST['columns']` function gets the data which i am using to query with. Though, when data is submitted with the use of a checkbox (so multiple values possible), its string in the database is a really weird one that the query (the WHERE) does not understand and so it returns nothing.

To make it a bit clearer, see the code below: 
**The HTML:**

```
<form method="post">    
    <div id="list3" class="dropdown-check-list">
        <span class="anchor">Select theme of Living Lab</span>
        <ul class="items">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Independent_living" />Independent living</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Chronic_heart_failure" />Chronic heart failure</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Dementia" />Dementia</li>    
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Prevention" />Prevention</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Other" />Other</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  

    <div id="list4" class="dropdown-check-list">
        <span class="anchor">Select stage of Living Lab</span>
        <ul class="items">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Starting_phase" />Starting phase</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Running_phase" />Running phase</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Completed" />Completed</li>      
        </ul>
    </div>  

<input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The first data list (themes of living lab) is data that is submitted through checkbox values (this is because there are multiple choices possible). The second data list (stage of living lab) is data that is submitted through radio buttons (so only 1 option is possible). The radio submitting creates just a normal string in the database, for example: completed. The thing is however that the checkbox submitting returns a weird string value in the database that is as follows: **when i only submit Prevention:** *a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:10:"Prevention";}*, and this **when i submit both prevention and dementia:** *a:3:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:8:"Dementia";i:2;s:10:"Prevention";}*.

**The php code that is being used to generate the field/filter which the query will search for is as follows:**

```
if(!empty($_POST['columns'])) { // empty() checks if the value is set before checking if it's empty.

    foreach($_POST['columns'] as $key_post=>$value_post){ 
    // Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
        $clean_criteria = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['columns']);

        // Convert the array into a string.
        $criteria = implode("','",$clean_criteria);


    }
```

This code works perfectly for the submitted radio button for example the string completed. When criteria is selected the $criteria will be set to the string 'completed' and the $criteria var is being given into the query.
Tho, this foreach doesn't seem to work with the previous mentioned checkbox values in the database. When i echo the $criteria variable (on a search selection of a checkbox field) it returns the value as it should, for example the prevention and/or dementia string, but these right strings can of course not be found in the database because the checkbox values in the database are so weird (like i mentioned before). So, what i think, is happening is the following: 1. a checkbox is selected and submitted. 2. the foreach loop sets the $criteria variable to the submitted checkbox value (so with prevention selected it returns the string 'prevention'). 3. the query searches for the word 'prevention' in the given database table and column. 4. because the value inside the database has all these weird markup (*a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:10:"Prevention";}*), the string prevention is not found.

**The query code is as follows:**

```
    $tmp = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT
            name_of_living_lab, location_of_living_lab, type_of_living_lab, theme_of_living_lab, stage_of_living_lab, living_lab_document           
        FROM           
            wp_participants_database            
        WHERE 
            theme_of_living_lab IN ('$criteria')    
        ORDER BY 
            name_of_living_lab ASC
    "); 

}
else {
//SOME ELSE ACTION - SHOW EVERYTHING
}
```

In the query example i only added the where statement for the themes (dementia, prevention, etc.) for testing purposes.

**I think the next piece of code is not really necessary but the code below displayed the queried data:**

```
echo "<table>
    <tr>";     
        echo "<th>Name of Living Lab</th>";
        echo "<th>Location of Living Lab</th>"; 
        echo "<th>Type of Living Lab</th>"; 
        echo "<th>Theme of Living Lab</th>";
        echo "<th>Stage of Living Lab</th>";    
        echo "<th>Living Lab document</th>";    
echo "</tr>";

if(count($tmp)>0){
    for($i=0;$i<count($tmp);$i++){
        echo "<tr>";  
            foreach($tmp[$i] as $key=>$value){
                echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";                 
            }           
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```

So to recap the stuff above: How can i pass the database checkbox values into the $criteria variable, which i can use for querying that specific data. Though, the $criteria variable also needs to be able to query normal string data (like the radio button submitted data which is just 1 string).

Thank you in advance!

***UPDATE***

It seemed quite easy to fix my problem, after some more research, by just using the LIKE %'$criteria%'. Though, the query results now show a serialized data in my front-end table that shows the data. So the only thing to do now is to un-serialize the query results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to do this instead:

```
        foreach($_POST['columns'] as $key_post=>$value_post){ 
            // Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
            // $clean_criteria = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['columns']);
               $clean_criteria[] = mysql_real_escape_string($value_post); // <---

            // Convert the array into a string.
            // $criteria = implode("','",$clean_criteria);
    }   

$criteria = implode("','",$clean_criteria);
```

Comment: @bultforce This returns the following errors: Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in /home/~~ on line 167
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/deb11421/domains/marceldepender.nl/public_html/Recap/wp-content/themes/radiate/templates/pdb-search-new.php on line 169. Perhaps also good to note that the main thing is that the checkbox uploading gives the weird values in the database and the $criteria is being set to the normal search string of the checkbox.

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay much attention. Got confused because of the foreach loop.

Try like this $clean_criteria[] = mysql_real_escape_string($value_post);

Comment: @bultforce Now the errors are gone, though, the $criteria var is still the normal string, but the database string is the one with the weird characters (so it wont work) since it doesnt search for the same. Now ive read something about wordpress adding these weird characters and you can fix this by unserialize it ($string = 'a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:10:"02/17/2014";i:1;s:10:"Thom Stark";}}';
$array = unserialize(trim($string));) though i think that this needs to be done in the uploading code... Or is it also possible to make the function work so it selects the data in the database and unserialize it

Comment: @bultforce it seemed quite easy to fix my problem by just using the LIKE %'$criteria%'. Though, the query results now show a serialized  data in my front-end table that shows the data. So the only thing to do now is to un-serialize the query results.